# How to remove Jackson "type" field on generics

Tags: spring-boot, jackson, marshalling

When a Spring Boot controller returns a generic object, Jackson marshals it and automatically adds a `"type"` field to the generated JSON. It basically marshals this object:

```
public class PaginatedResponse<T> {
    List<T> list;
    int total;

    // ctors, getters and setters
}
```

The marshaled response looks like this:

```
{
    "list":[
        {"type": "foo", "id": 1},
        {"type": "foo", "id": 2}
    ],
    "total": 2
}
```

whereas I would like to get this:

```
{
    "list":[
        {"id": 1},
        {"id": 2}
    ],
    "total": 2
}
```

I do understand the purpose of this mechanism, but this JSON will not be unmarshaled back to the original `PaginatedResponse` object and I'd like to drop the `"type"` field. How can I do that?

I'm using Jackson 2.7.6 within Spring Boot 1.4.5 with no Jackson-specific settings in the properties file or Jackson annotations on either of the unmarshaled objects.

Comment: can you share controller code

Comment: The controller is a one-liner, calling the service. The service in turn just returns `new PaginatedResponse<> (...)`. The arguments are raw data models fetched from the database. No type field there.

Comment: I know it's been more than one year and a half but could you solve it? Could you share your model class `foo`?

Comment: The project that this issue appeared in was canceled, so I can't provide any code at this point anymore. I recall someone ended up fixing this issue, but I'm unaware of the change that was required.